# rectForRowAtIndexPath doesn't work with iOS8

Tags: uitableview, ios8, xcode6

I have a project that uses rectForRowAtIndexPath to get a frame from a cell, but when I build on iOS8 simulator the frame returns 0, but in iOS7 simulator it's working normally.

Anyone had the same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If tableView does not finished loading, cell is unvisible, then `rectForRowAtIndexPath` returns 0.

Try to delay 0.1 seconds or more, like this:

```
    [self.tableView reloadData];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGRect cellFrame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }];;
});
```